# Recursive function implementation for Binary search tree

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement a basic Binary search tree.

I was able to create a `Node` and I have problems with the `AddNode()` function. It is supposed to add a new node to the existing tree but it `replaces` it.

Any ideas what should be done in the `AddNode()` function ?

```
class Node
{
    public int value { get; set; }

    public Node left { get; set; }

    public Node right { get; set; }

    public Node(int i)
    {
        this.value = i;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }

}

class Tree
{
    public Node root { get; set; }

    public Tree(Node n)
    {
        root = n;
    }

    public void AddNode(int valueToBeInserted)
    {
        if (this.root == null)
        {
            this.root = new Node(valueToBeInserted); 
            // problem here : existing tree is destroyed. 
            // a new one is created. 
            // instead it should add a new node to the end of the tree if its null
        }

        if (valueToBeInserted < this.root.value)
        {
            this.root = this.root.left;
            this.AddNode(valueToBeInserted);
        }

        if (valueToBeInserted > this.root.value)
        {
            this.root = this.root.right;
            this.AddNode(valueToBeInserted);
        }
    }

    public void printTree()
    {
        // print recursively the values here.
    }
}

class TreeTest
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var tree = new Tree(new Node(100));
        tree.AddNode(20);
        tree.AddNode(100);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the point of writing `public int value { get; set; }` instead of `public int value;`?

Comment: @PaulDraper: ya, no special case. thanks for bringing that up. But, do you know how I should write the function for `AddNode` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These lines replace the root:

```
this.root = this.root.left;
this.root = this.root.right;
```

You should instead pass a parameter to your recursive function.

You can also remove the `this` quantifiers - they're only necessary when you have a local variable with the same name or perhaps in some other corner cases.

Adding a helper function is useful / necessary since the root must be catered for separately.

Updated code:

```
public void AddNode(int valueToBeInserted)
{
    if (root == null)
    {
        root = new Node(valueToBeInserted);
    }
    else
    {
        AddNode(valueToBeInserted, root);
    }
}

private void AddNode(int valueToBeInserted, Node current)
{
    if (valueToBeInserted < current.value)
    {
        if (current.left == null)
            current.left = new Node(valueToBeInserted);
        else
            AddNode(valueToBeInserted, current.left);
    }

    if (valueToBeInserted > current.value)
    {
        if (current.right == null)
            current.right = new Node(valueToBeInserted);
        else
            AddNode(valueToBeInserted, current.right);
    }
}
```

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. How you tested it? clearly, there is no function "AddRoot" here, it should be "AddNode". Isn't it?

Comment: @RajeshMishra Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This statement will only be true the first time you run your code.

```
if (this.root == null)
{
    this.root = new Node(valueToBeInserted);
}
```

Nowhere does the this.root get set to null again...
Normally you would code the add like this:

```
public void AddNode(int valueToBeInserted)
{
    if (this.root == null)
    {
        this.root = new Node(valueToBeInserted); 
    }

    if (valueToBeInserted < this.root.value)
    {
        this.root.left = this.AddNode(valueToBeInserted);
        this.root = this.root.left;
    }

    if (valueToBeInserted > this.root.value)
    {
        this.root.right = this.AddNode(valueToBeInserted);
        this.root = this.root.right;
    }
}
```